# Discover all possible stakeholders in a pile of (legacy) systems

Tags: software-industry, communication, management, project-management

I have been assigned a team that seems to have been "abandoned" in the following sense: Hadn't had a direct manager for a long time and has been getting more and more responsibilities of what we say legacy things essentially making it similar to a "dumpster".

The people that I directly work with do not know all the relevant stakeholders that the team has and this complicate things a lot.

My plan is to start digging into each area of responsibility all the relevant parties but my question is:

Is there a structured approach to connect the dots that at the same time wouldn't make the existing people in the area (including my manager) look "bad"? i.e. that people around don't know this information.

Comment: In what capacity you've been asigned to the team? What's your position, goals to achieve etc?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this question? An exhaustive search method to definitively and accurately list everyone in your company who may have any kind of investment or opinion on a project, and without somehow revealing it to said person that you've clearly lost the plot? I mean, how do you expect an internet stranger to tell you your company structure and how it communicates?

Comment: Not sure what we can tell you besides "Find everyone who is using anything you're supporting, using whatever channels of communication are available to you -- possibly including putting a message to the users into the start-up screen "Hey, we're trying to make sure we're aware of everyone who's using this; if you haven't already done so, please drop a note to flebic-support@ourcompany to tell us how you're using it, what you like about it, what could be improved, and what your highest priorities are for us to work on next (budget permitting). Thanks!"

Comment: @keshlam: Yes this is similar to what I had in mind. I was interested if perhaps there is some other more "formalised" approach.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Ask what? About what approach to follow?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere:she does not know all the stakeholders. She joined a bit before me and I think the previous manager she replaced from what I have seen did not keep up the area in a good shape

Comment: If this team is getting more and more responsibilities, who is assigning those new responsibilities?

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple.

You formally ask your manager who all the stake holders are.

If they don't know, then with the managers permission you ask everyone else who might know.

> Is there a structured approach to connect the dots that at the same time wouldn't make the existing people in the area (including my manager) look "bad"?

This isn't your problem, but there is no reason anyone should look bad, you're just gathering information. If your manager doesn't know and tasks you with finding out, then that's pretty normal procedure.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find the stakeholders on legacy systems is to turn something off and see if anyone notices. With legacy systems, a lot of times, the systems are not supporting anything critical. Or if they are, there can be a lot of unnecessary overhead that is no longer needed. By turning things off, you will find out what is really needed.

For example, a client turned off a system at their level but left a lot of AWS automatic processes running. They finally brought in someone who knew AWS to reduce the monthly costs. They had several databases that were no longer being used.

Edit: One common problem with many legacy systems is that the people who knew the stakeholders are no longer with the company. Asking within the company won't find the answers because nobody still with the company knows. I've had clients call me because their technical people had moved on, their system was malfunctioning, and I still had my notes from 5 years ago and could fix the problem.

In other words, about the only way to find who the current stakeholders are is to turn the system off and see who notices. The way to do this is to announce that "System X will be going down for maintenance on . We do not know how many days it will be down. If you know that your operations will be affected, please call XXXXX to tell us. Or once it is down and you are affected, please call and let us know."

Comment: This is a very situational answer, "legacy" is a very broadly defined term. Imagine just switching things off and they are needed for some vital part of the companies business. This is more a funny answer than actual advice i feel like.

Comment: @kirbby, This is actually a viable technique. It is used extensively in testing disaster recovery processes: turn off a process and see what else is affected that shouldn't be and verify that the recovery process works. (See AWS recovery.) I would not do it without making sure that people can communicate that they need what was just turned off. Other ways of identifying all the stakeholders can wind up being O(n) time consumers.

Comment: I call that the "scream test" - turn it off and see who screams!

Answer (score 0):

Email a survey to the stakeholders that you're aware of. This could be a discovery survey to learn about whatever problem you're trying to solve or understand your stakeholder needs. Include the question, "Who else is involved in this?".